# Retrieving an int from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

How do I retrieve an int from NSUserDefaults?

I have the following code

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *prefs = [def arrayForKey:@"addedFavs"];    
favList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:prefs];
```

If I try this

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int tempInt = [def objectForKey:@"addedFavs"];
```

will I not need to do type casting?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `-[NSUserDefaults setInteger:forKey:]` to store the value and `-[NSUserDefaults integerForKey]` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked in at NSUserDefaults in the documentation? There is a `integerForKey:` method that will retrieve an integer for a given key.

```
NSInteger tempInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"aKey"];
```